# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class play.data.format.Formatters

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, playframework-2.1

I'm using Play 2.1.2 and I want to use dynamic forms. I tried it in my own small hello world project and everything worked fine, but when I use forms in other bigger project I'm getting an exception. Here is my code (in both project is the same):

**Controller**

```
public static Result signInForm() {
    DynamicForm form = Form.form().bindFromRequest();   //exception on this line
    return renderJapid(form);
}
```

**Routes**

```
GET     /sign-in                                            controllers.Authentication.signInForm()
```

When I go to localhost:9000/sign-in I get this **exception**:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class play.data.format.Formatters
at play.data.Form.bind(Form.java:320) ~[play-java_2.10.jar:2.1.2]
at play.data.DynamicForm.bind(DynamicForm.java:100) ~[play-java_2.10.jar:2.1.2]
at play.data.DynamicForm.bindFromRequest(DynamicForm.java:71) ~[play-java_2.10.jar:2.1.2]
at controllers.Authentication.signInForm(Authentication.java:310) ~[na:na]
at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$19$$anonfun$apply$19.apply(routes_routing.scala:305) ~[na:na]
at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$19$$anonfun$apply$19.apply(routes_routing.scala:305) ~[na:na]
```

Please, can you help me? Where could be the problem? I've checked Global.java and application.conf in both projects but I didn't find anything what could cause this problem.

**UPDATE**:

I've tried to put this code

```
FormattingConversionService fcs = Formatters.conversion;
```

before the line with the dynamic form call. After reloading localhost:9000/sign-in in browser I got this exception on that new line:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at play.data.format.Formatters.register(Formatters.java:186) ~[play-java_2.10.jar:2.1.2]
at play.data.format.Formatters.<clinit>(Formatters.java:100) ~[play-java_2.10.jar:2.1.2]
at controllers.Authentication.signInForm(Authentication.java:310) ~[na:na]
at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$19$$anonfun$apply$19.apply(routes_routing.scala:305) ~[na:na]
at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$19$$anonfun$apply$19.apply(routes_routing.scala:305) ~[na:na]
at play.core.Router$HandlerInvoker$$anon$6$$anon$2.invocation(Router.scala:175) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.2]
```

So it seems that Formatters is in the classpath. But when I hit the reload button in the browser again I get the same NoClassDefFoundError as before (this time on the line which I added).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NoClassDefFoundError usually means that the class is not on the classpath. Possibly it was there when you compiled it, but now it is missing (seen this with shared libraries mostly).

[NoClassDefFoundError documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html)

Looks like it is probably not finding play-java_2.10.jar.

**EDIT:**(to sum up the comments)

The Play jar uses Spring for binding data. Initial thought was Spring was not included on classpath, but it was. However, the Spring on the classpath appears to have a conflict with some Spring jars in the lib folder. Removing the jars in the lib folder seems to have cleared up the error.  :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think if play-java_2.10.jar is missing it will cause problems on other places as well. I have updated my question so you can check it.

Comment: @user2545521 actually you would be better to ask another one because those two problems doesn't seem to be related to each other. Don't ask new one right now, but try to stick to this principle in future.

Comment: Another possible cause is an error during initialization that does not get caught properly and ends up bubbling up into a NoClassDefFoundError. It also looks like play uses Spring for binding data, so possibly Spring is missing from your classpath, but the error ends up coming out as a class failing to initialize.

Comment: @om-nom-nom I don't think they are not related. I only tried to use the Formatter class before that call to check if it is in classpath at runtime. Now I got both exceptions with the same code and in both cases it has to do something with the Formatter class.

Comment: @BlakeP I checked it and spring is in the classpath as well

Comment: @BlakeP Thank you for your post with the spring. I found out that I got some spring jars in my lib folder. When I removed these jars everything works. So I think there was some conflict with the versions of the spring libraries.

Comment: Ah, yes, if the versions aren't the same there will likely be a conflict. I will update my answer to include the new info.  :)